# Showing an inequality involving a sequence

Tags: real-analysis

$(a_n)$ is a positive strictly increasing sequence. I have to show that $(a_{2n-1}a_{2n+1})^{0.5} < a_{2n}$. I can use the AM GM inequality to show that $(a_{2n-1}a_{2n+1})^{0.5}$ $\leq ((a_{2n-1} + a_{2n+1}))/2 < ((a_{2n} + a_{2n+1}))/2$.

Answer (score 1):

It is obviously false. Consider the following counter-example:
1, 2, 10000000000, (the remaining terms are not important)

Do you think $\sqrt{1\times 10000000000} < 2$?